# Control block hierarchy. hide all div but one with particular class

Tags: css

```
.PaneToBehiddenForMobile
    {
        display: none;
    }
```

DnnModule-ListBlogByCategory

I have a div with following class PaneToBehiddenForMobile
I have a inner div with DnnModule-ListBlogByCategory

```
<div class="PaneToBehiddenForMobile">
    <div class="DnnModule-ListBlogByCategory">

    </div>
 <a ...></a>
 <table>....</table>
    <div class="XYZ">

    </div>
    <div >

    </div>
</div>
```

In css I have set `PaneToBehiddenForMobile` visibility to none so that all div and element inside this will be hidden

Now what i wanted is that one particular div with class `DnnModule-ListBlogByCategory` should be visible while all other have same behavior
How can i do it with only css

Comment: In short, you cannot do that

Answer (score 4):

You can hide all the divs inside the `PaneToBehiddenForMobile` div instead of hiding itself and show only the required div. Here is the CSS snippet for that:

```
.PaneToBehiddenForMobile div {
    display: none;
}

.PaneToBehiddenForMobile .DnnModule-ListBlogByCategory {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: The reason I prefer the `:not()` pseudo selector is what if a <p> gets added... or a <ul>... css adjustments will be required for a (possibly) content only change.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would use the `:not()` pseudo selector (CSS3). Like so:

```
.PaneToBehiddenForMobile div:not(.DnnModule-ListBlogByCategory){
    display:none;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zMfdQ/

Of course you'll want to do a media selector or server side choose what css to send so that that only applies to mobile views.

HTH
NIck

Comment: The only problem with this is when the element you want to display is further nested...

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
.PaneToBehiddenForMobile
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is already there and working.I think you might not understood the question.